# I have monthly mean data for 25 years, and I want to take the mean of each month over all the years, is my for loop correct?

Tags: python

I have 1D monthly data ranging from 1992 - 2016. I want to take say, the means of all the January values from 1992 - 2016 in order to isolate the seasonal variation. Is my for loop doing the right thing?

```
test_mean = []

for months in range(lsds_detrend_mnths.size):
    mean = np.mean(lsds_detrend_mnths[months::months+1])
    test_mean.append(mean)
```

Am I using the array slicing properly?

Or in order to take the average of every month for all years, do I do this for loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you data starts on January you should use this to get mean for January:

`mean = np.mean(lsds_detrend_mnths[::12])`

This will be mean for January.And to get mean for other months you can use this loop:

```
for i in range(12):
    test_mean.append(np.mean(lsds_detrend_mnths[i::12]))
```

Just remember what slice notation means:

`a[start:stop:step] # start through not past stop, by step`

Comment: @wabash And why do you consider it strange.Can you show what was expected?

Comment: @wabash If data that you have is ordered by months - then it definitely should do what you want. And plot looks alright for me.